# Application/Places/System menu in Unity

Tags: unity, panel

I have disabled the global menu and want to put the classic Application/Places/System menu in its place. How would I go about doing that in Ubuntu 12.04LTS?

(Note: I do want to try keeping unity as well as the dock launcher around for now to see if I can get used to that)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Classic Menu Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) to get an category-sorted application menu in Unity. Another way is to install *gnome-session-fallback* and to select the GNOME Fallback Mode at login, which makes GNOME 3 to imitate the look and feel of GNOME 2. You could also consider to switch to XFCE, which is quite similiar to GNOME 2.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the Classic Menu Indicator. I did this:

pressed Ctrl – Alt – T on my keyboard to open Terminal. Typed this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:diesch/testing
```

then this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

Restarted my computer and saw the indicator menu on the top panel.